How can I customize django TextField for Inline Editor
I'm developing an internet forum platform using Django and facing a challenge regarding the customization of the TextField to support inline editor without third-party editors such as TinyMCE or CKEditor.
The objective is to empower users to compose rich content including code snippets, links, images, tables, and formatted text directly within the TextField. However, after I found a tutorial, I haven't found a clear solution for implementing inline editor functionality.
I want to create inline editor that uses different special characters to display content in the browser.
Could anyone point us an examples or documentation for customizing Django TextField to support inline editor?

If you don't want to adopt existing editors, you are going to have to take on a lot of work and responsibility writing your own editor for the frontend, and then writing the necessary cleaning and security for the back end content. I can't really advise you because I haven't solved this problem.
In the front end, I think (other than inspecting the source of CKeditor etc) the best leg up I found is this. There is a section here labeled "A simple but complete text editor" which is amazing, but I don't feel like I can tell you its a secure, ready for prime time thing.  Maybe it is.  It doesn't do embedded js etc, but you can probably support it by changing the styles.
In the back end, Adam Johnson has a post about adding basic html cleaning in the right places for Django.  Again, you want at least this, but I don't know that there aren't a whole lot of other things you should also do.
